# Why is the Temp.prototype on the MDN Object.create polyfill set to null?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

Why does the MDN polyfill for Object.create have the following line:

```
Temp.prototype = null;
```

Is it so that we avoid maintaining a reference to the prototype argument enabling faster garbage collection?

The polyfill:

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  Object.create = (function() {
    var Temp = function() {};
    return function (prototype) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
        throw Error('Second argument not supported');
      }
      if (typeof prototype != 'object') {
        throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
      }
      Temp.prototype = prototype;
      var result = new Temp();
      Temp.prototype = null;
      return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. This polyfill does hold the `Temp` function forever in memory (so that its faster on average, not needing to create a function for every invocation of `create`), and resetting the `.prototype` on it is necessary so that it does not leak.

Comment: Not exactly. `Object.create = (function() {})();` is an immediately-invoked function expression. How could it be `hold the Temp function forever in memory` anyway? Actually I think the last `Temp.prototype = null;` is unnecessary.

Comment: -- update.
I think I made a mistake. The returned function is hold by Object.create, that's forever in memory.

Comment: @SimonGong: The function that is returned from the IEFE and assigned to `Object.create` is a closure, which has a reference to the `Temp` function. And as long as the closure is not garbage collected (supposedly never), the `Temp` function is held in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just clean, Temp.prototype is kind of static, since it is set before new Temp() it is nice to clean it after.